# Scilab: tell if we are running headless. Scilab: detect -nw, -nogui

Tags: makefile, terminal, automation, scilab, headless

**Scilab can really be automated.**
For instance you can use `make` to automatically start Scilab that will generate plots and save them to SVG with `xs2svg`, then start Inkscape to integrate it into a Latex document (with Latex code in legends!).

When using `make` it is convenient to run Scilab without the main interface by calling it with `-nw`. If you do not need graphics it can even run without java if called with `-nogui`.

**It would be nice to be able to write scripts that can be either run by a user or by `make`.** With that you could prevent code duplication while allowing easy debugging and report writing.
But that means:

- closing the script when it's done
- being able to skip some plots that should not be saved
- etc

## So how to detect options `-nw` or `-nogui` from within the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using `getargs`

```
function y = nowindows()
    y = (getenv("SCILAB_NW","undefined") ~= "undefined")
endfunction
```

then you can use this function:

```
if nowindows() then
    mprintf("Running without a window.\n")
    exit()
end
```

And if you set the environnement variable SCILAB_NW, nowindows() will return true.

> SCILAB_NW="true" scilab -nw -f yourscript.sce

This solution adds redundancy to the command used to run Scilab but I found no other way. I also tried to use the `sciargs` function but I found it less convenient.